# Keras models in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm building image processing network in tensorflow and I want to make use of texture loss. Texture loss seems simple to implement if you have pretrained model loaded.

I'm using TF to build the computational graph for my model and I want to incorporate Keras.application.VGG19 model to get output from layer 'block4_conv4'.

The problem is: I have two TF tensors target and result from my main model, how to feed them into keras VGG19 in the same session to compute their diff and use it in main loss for my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems following code does the trick

```
with tf.variable_scope("") as scope:
    phi_func = VGG19(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=(128, 128, 3))

    text_1 = phi_func(predicted)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    text_2 = phi_func(x)

    text_loss = tf.reduce_mean((text_1 - text_2)**2)
```

- right after session created I call `phi_func.load_weights(path)` to initiate weights